# Delete a line from a PDF and creating a new PDF with these modifications

Tags: python, pdf

I currently have this code:

```
def delete_first_line_from_pages(pages_indices, input_pdf_path, output_pdf_path):
    with open(input_pdf_path, 'rb') as input_file, open(output_pdf_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(input_file)
        for page_index in range(len(reader.pages)):
            page = reader.pages[page_index]
            if page_index in pages_indices:
                content = page.extract_text()
                lines = content.split("\n")
                if lines:
                    first_line = next(line for line in lines if line.strip())
                    if first_line:
                        modified_content = content.replace(first_line, '', 1)
                    else:
                        modified_content = content
```

where I end up with modified_content which is basically the text of the page with the first line of text removed. From now on I want to create a page element that has the same structure of the source but this new modified_content as text.
My final goal is to save to an output_path the pdf I had as input but removing the first line of each page.
How can I do it?

Comment: This seems needlessly complicated. Why not something like: `lines = content.split("\n")[1:]`?

Comment: @erip I tried but it doesn't work in most of the times, I assume it is because my text is usually in the form "\n\nFIRSTLINE\nSECONDLINE". Using my code I am sure that modified_content will contain what I want (in the example "\n\n\nSECONDLINE"

Answer (score 0):

Solution using PyMuPDF.

This uses PDF redaction annotations.

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

doc=fitz.open("input.pdf")
for page in doc:
    blocks = page.get_text("dict", sort=True)["blocks"]
    block = block[0]  # first text paragraph on page
    line = block["lines"][0]  # fist line in block
    bbox = line["bbox"]  # boundary box of that line
    page.add_redact_annot(bbox)  # wrap in a redact annot
    page.apply_redactions()  # remove stuff inside (the text)

doc.ez_save("output.pdf")
```